# How to fix my Intel 8265 / 8275 network unclaimed wifi

Tags: drivers, iwlwifi

When I run `sudo lshw -C network` it shows:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a6b00000-a6b01fff
```

What should I do?